# convert date from yyyy-mm-dd to dd month yyyy

Tags: r, date

I had different formats of dates in the "Date" column of my dataframe. I bought them to same format using anytime library.

```
library(anytime)
anytime(final.df$Date)
```

The `anytime()` function returned the date in "2020-01-14" (i.e. yyyy-mm-dd) format. I want to convert this format to "dd Month yyyy".

Example: "2020-01-14" should be converted to 14 January 2020.
Any direct function in R to achieve it or any suggested workaround.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `format` after converting date to one standard format using `anytime`. Read `?strptime` to know about various formats for date and time.

```
final.df$Date <- anytime::anytime(final.df$Date)  
final.df$Date <- format(final.df$Date, "%d %B %Y")
```

For example,

```
format(Sys.Date(), "%d %B %Y")
#[1] "15 January 2020"
```

Comment: why this was downvoted? it gives the desired output

Comment: This is working as required. Dont know why it was downvoted. Thanks Ronak.